# DataFrame.shift() with timeseries index results in NonExistentTimeerror

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe in which I need to shift some of the columns by various times (all shift times are multiples of 15m). The index is a datetime index, but it is not complete / has gaps. All data is at a 15 minute frequency. I am using the following code to make the shift:

```
df['varb_shift']=df['varb'].shift(-1,freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=15))
```

I'm receiving the NonExistentTimeError for the time 2019-03-31 02:45:00 (CET or UTC+2). This makes sense, since I have data at 2019-03-31 03:00:00 +2:00. However, I'm not sure how to deal with it, aside from deleting the data near the boundary. I looked into DateOffset() and don't see an apparent way to indicate that it should take timezones into account and not shift into non-existent times.

I feel like there's an easy solution but I haven't found it yet. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

While maybe not pretty, I was able to solve this problem by converting to UTC, performing the shift, and then converting back to CET.

```
df = df.tz_convert('UTC')
df['varb_shift']=df['varb'].shift(-1,freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=15))
df = df.tz_convert('CET')
```

Comment: CET is just a UTC offset, you might want to use a IANA time zone instead - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones